# Как обратится к обработчику без перехода на страницу с его содержанием?

Tags: php, html

У меня на странице есть форма в которой я заполняю поля и жму кнопку на сохранение, в итоге он у меня посылает все это обработчику находящему в  другом файле php и открывает эту страницу с сообщением об изменениях. А мне нужно, чтоб он выводил это сообщение сразу на той же странице, где была нажата кнопка сохранении.

P.S.

Если что, делаю всплывающее окно с сообщением от обработчика.

```
<form action='save_edit.php' method='post'>
 <td>
   <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()"><input type='submit' name='submit'      class="button3" value='Сохранить'></a>  
   </td> 
   </form>
```

Вот код с обработчика

```
        ////////////////////////
        if (isset($_POST['sport']))//Если существует имя
              {
        $sport = $_POST['sport'];          
    $result4 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET    sport='$sport' WHERE login='$login'",$db);//обновляем в базе  
    echo "<html><head><meta    http-equiv='Refresh' content='5;    URL=page.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']."'></head><body>Ваши данные изменены! Вы    будете перемещены через 5 сек. Если не хотите ждать, то <a    href='page.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']."'>нажмите    сюда.</a></body></html>";//отправляем    пользователя назад
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто: вам нужно узнать что из себя представляет технология AJAX. При нажатии на кнопку вы будете посылать запрос на сервер, где будет что-то производится и возвращаться ответ в виде сообщения, которое вы без труда вставите в нужное вам место на странице.

PS. Экранируйте входящие данные, хотя бы с помощью `mysqli_real_escape_string`, иначе ваш код будет небезопасным.

UPDATE: Схематично набросал вам что должно быть:

Форма:

```
<form action='server.php' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
</form>
<div class="message"></div>
```

Клиент (jQuery):

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var value = $(this).find('input[name="data"]').val();
    $.post(
        'server.php',
        {'value': value},
        function(data) {
            $('.message').html(data);
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

Сервер:

```
if (isset($_POST['value']) && !empty(_POST['value'])) {
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, trim($_POST['value']));
    $query = 'UPDATE users SET
                     value = ' . $value . '
                     WHERE login = ' . $login;          
    if (mysqli_query($database, $query) {
        echo 'Данные успешно обновлены';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да сделал я через Ajax, спасибо.